# How can I add this new custom column to the output of my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [Date],
    (CASE
        WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-06-30' THEN 'FY 16-17'
        WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-06-30' THEN 'FY 17-18'
        WHEN [Date] BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'FY 18-19'
        ELSE 'Not Stated'
     END) AS [Period]
FROM 
    DateDimension
WHERE  
    [Date] BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2019-06-30'
```

The output is as follows (extract):

```
Date          Period
-----------------------
2016-07-01    FY 16-17
2016-07-02    FY 16-17
2016-07-03    FY 16-17
...           ...
2017-07-01    FY 17-18
2017-07-02    FY 17-18
2017-07-03    FY 17-18
...           ...
2018-07-01    FY 18-19
2018-07-02    FY 18-19
2018-07-03    FY 18-19
...           ...
```

I want to add a new column to the output as follows:

```
    Date          Period       Day
    -------------------------------
    2016-07-01    FY 16-17     D1
    2016-07-02    FY 16-17     D2
    2016-07-03    FY 16-17     D3
    ...           ...          ...
    2017-07-01    FY 17-18     D1
    2017-07-02    FY 17-18     D2
    2017-07-03    FY 17-18     D3
    ...           ...          ...
    2018-07-01    FY 18-19     D1
    2018-07-02    FY 18-19     D2
    2018-07-03    FY 18-19     D3
    ...           ...          ...
```

To note that `D1` starts again at the beginning of each new financial year (that is,`2016-07-01`, `2017-07-01` and `2018-07-01`).

How do I write the SQL code for this new column?

Additional note: `D1` should be continuous till the end of each financial year. Example, from `2016-07-01` till `2017-06-30`, column `Period` will show D1, D2, ..., D365)

Comment: You are selecting from a table called `DateDimension`. I would expect this table to already contain date-related columns such as what financial year does the current date belong to and what day it is in that financial year...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
 SELECT [Date]
,(CASE WHEN [Date] between '2016-07-01' and '2017-06-30' THEN 'FY 16-17'
      WHEN [Date] between '2017-07-01' and '2018-06-30' THEN 'FY 17-18'
      WHEN [Date] between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-30' THEN 'FY 18-19'
      ELSE 'Not Stated'
      END) as [Period]
FROM DateDimension
)

select *,concat('D',row_number() over(partition by period order by date)) as DayNo
    from cte
```

Comment: It seems you missed the point that you must start counting on July 1.

Comment: Also, a single missing day in the table turns `row_number()` into pumpkin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DATEDIFF` to get the difference in days between the start of the financial year & `[Date]`.

```
SELECT 

[Date]
,(CASE WHEN [Date] between '2016-07-01' and '2017-06-30' THEN 'FY 16-17'
  WHEN [Date] between '2017-07-01' and '2018-06-30' THEN 'FY 17-18'
  WHEN [Date] between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-30' THEN 'FY 18-19'
  ELSE 'Not Stated'
  END) as [Period]
, CASE WHEN [Date] < DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()), 7, 1)
       THEN CONCAT('D', (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(Year, [Date]) - 1, 7, 1), [Date] + 1)))
       ELSE CONCAT('D', (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(Year, [Date]), 7, 1), [Date] + 1)))
  END AS [Day]

FROM DateDimension

WHERE [Date] between '2016-07-01' and '2019-06-30'
```

This method also means that the dates could be in any order or even have some days missing & the `Day` column should still be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can simplify your existing FY calculation, and get the day of financial year as well:

```
declare @date date = '20190702';

select year(dateadd(month, -6, @date)) as [FY],
  datediff(day, datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -6, @date)), 6, 30), @date) as [DOFY];
```

The hard-coded constants that designate the offset between the calendar and financial year can also be parameterised, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF` to calculate number of days in that Financial year. You just need an extra effort to get the Financial year first date for the DATE column.

```
DECLARE @DateDimension TABLE ([DATE] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @DateDimension
SELECT '2019-03-25' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2018-12-06'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2018-05-15'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2017-11-22'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2019-07-06'

SELECT  [DATE]
,'D'+CAST( DATEDIFF(DD, CASE WHEN MONTH([DATE]) BETWEEN 7 AND 12 
        THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([DATE]),07,01) 
        ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([DATE])-1,07,01) END,[DATE])+1 
    AS VARCHAR(3)) AS DAY_IN_FY
FROM @DateDimension
```

**Result:**

```
+-------------------------+-----------+
|          DATE           | DAY_IN_FY |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| 2019-03-25 00:00:00.000 | D268      |
| 2018-12-06 00:00:00.000 | D159      |
| 2018-05-15 00:00:00.000 | D319      |
| 2017-11-22 00:00:00.000 | D145      |
| 2019-07-06 00:00:00.000 | D6        |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that you can express the query as:

```
SELECT d.[Date], v.period,
       CONCAT('D', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY period ORDER BY date)) as [Day]
FROM DateDimension dd CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (RIGHT(DATENAME(year, d.[Date]), 2) + '-' +
              RIGHT(DATENAME(year, DATEADD(year, 1, d.[Date])), 2) 
             )
     ) as v(period)
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2019-06-30';
```

The `period` can also be defined as:

```
     (VALUES (CONCAT(YEAR([Date] % 100, '-',
                     1 + YEAR([Date] % 100
                    )
             )
     ) as v(period)
```